# How to "disarm and kill agile guards with their own weapon"?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

One of the Abstergo challenges in the fighter category says:

> disarm and kill 3 agile guards with their own weapon

I've been disarming them left and right, but they always drop their weapon and I somehow can't pick them up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The agile guards use throwing knives as weapon, of which you can only carry 1 at a time. If you drop their weapon to the ground, it's most likely you already carry a throwing knife. If that's the case, just kill the guard with the knife you already have.

The best way to finish the challenge is by doing the following:

- Equip your fists (unarmed) and the throwing knife (it doesn't matter if you've got one or not)
- Initiate combat with an agile guard (they are the ones that don't wear hats)
- Wait for them to attack, then disarm them by pressing *counter* followed by *break defense*.
- Press *shoot* to throw your knife, killing the guard in the process.
- Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 8):

So I've been looking around for this same answer and have finally found it!

If you are on the PC version and using keyboard and mouse, there is a bug! This bug DOES NOT SELECT THE THROWING KNIFE FROM YOUR SIDE WEAPONS! Because of this, if you ever obtain one, it will only disarm the guard by dropping the knife to the ground. To get around this, switch to using a controller, as they seem to have forgotten to map a button for the throwing knife (possibly due to the fact you can only get them through disarming, but still an oversight that they should have noticed). Use the d-pad to select the throwing knife you already have in stock, and use it on any old guard to get rid of it. Afterwards, you can switch back to using the keyboard if you wish and the next time you disarm an agile guard, you'll automatically have the knife selected, so simply use it on them.

Hope this helped if you were using the PC version, and if not, hope this helped anyone else who found their way here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I'm playing on the PS3, so I wasn't aware of a PC bug. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve the knife bug (pc version) there is another solution... Search the file "Assassin4.ini" and Enable a keymap for use the Dpad.... Open Assassin4.ini (notepad) and search for:

```
....

[KeyboardMouse2 DefaultBindings]

...

PadUp=-1
PadRight=-1
PadDown=-1
PadLeft=-1

....
```

By default the -1 is for disable ... change in:

```
PadUp=12
PadRight=27
PadDown=26
PadLeft=25
```

(...)

12 is Keyboard  key "?"

27 is keyboard key "+"

26 is keyboard key "è"

25 is keyboard key "p"

In game can use the keyboard for emulate the Dpad and select the knife...

(the assassin4.ini file is under documents in Assassin IV Black Flag directory)

Comment: Um, what do you want to say by this? I don't see any 'change this'...

Comment: You don't have too change the .ini file, just press shift and then scroll. This should pop up the tools menu, the knife is at the top of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Simply walk up to a agile guard and attack them, but make sure you have your fists equipped.

Punch them once, wait for them to attack, counter the attack, then press <kbd>A</kbd> (Xbox 360). It should then be only a few hits with the weapon you just disarmed off of the guard and it's done.

Repeat this until the challenge is completed.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to be unarmed (select the little fists icon as your weapon). Then, when you disarm by holding B, on Xbox, then A… you'll end up with their weapon in your hand. A few hacks of the sword and repeat with another guard.

Answer (score 1):

In the AC4 PC version, you can select the throwing knife if you hold the **Q** button. The primary weapon icons pops up (showing unarmed, hidden blades and swords). Still holding the **Q** button, rotate the wheel on the mouse, the secondary weapon icons pops up. It will show the throwing knife just above the 'coins' icon. 
Select it and then you can complete the Abstergo Challenge.

Comment: That doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Originally posted as [a separate question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397838/abstergo-challenge-disarm-and-kill-3-agile-guards-with-their-own-weapon) by Popelnice Lojidná

> In sequence 10, memory 3, your quest is to "clean the jungle" and "clean the caves" and there are guards with knives. I don't know why but if you go unarmed, wait for them to attack you, counter and disarm them, you'll take their knive. And if you throw that knive the moment you got it, you'll kil them one after one (if there is more of course) and that counts for some reason.